# How do I set visibility priority of objects? Chat app. Java Jframe, Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm making a chat app. that looks like this:

[image: http://puu.sh/k5wsp/718e56afe1.png]

I have a submenu called "private" that toggles the users rights to read chatlogs.

[image: http://puu.sh/k5wuR/493faddcb4.png]

However, when I read chatlogs into the Jtextarea (the chatbox), the submenus appear behind the chat history label.

[image: http://puu.sh/k5wxY/b1e81160d3.png]

The label isn't a component of the Jtextarea. How do I fix this?

**EDIT** More information. I know that the problem occurs when I read in a chatlog, because I no longer have this problem when removing the following from the code.
 `chatBox.read(reader, chatLog);` 
What I mean by not having this problem is, I can toggle the private on and off and click on objects in the friendlist, without the "chatroom" label getting in the way of the submenu.

Comment: is your gui getting freeze  when  read chatlogs ?

Comment: It might be freezing for a splitsecond but I can't tell at all.

Comment: Is the label a `Label` or a `JLabel`?  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: It is a label. I'll add more information about the problem.

Comment: Don't use a `Label`. That is an AWT component. Use a `JLabel` which is a Swing component.

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer? That solved the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't use a Label. That is an AWT component. Use a JLabel which is a Swing component. –  camickr